# How to hide GetType() method from COM?

Tags: com, hide, excel-formula, gettype

I made an automation Add-In for Excel, and I made several functions (formulas).

I have a class which header looks like this (it is COM visible):

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Functions
{}
```

In a list of methods, I see:

```
 ToString(), Equals(), GetHashCode() and GetType() methods.
```

Since all methods of my class are COM visible, I should somehow hide those 4.
I succeeded with 3 of them:

```
ToString(), Equals(), GetHashCode()
```

but GetType() cannot be overriden.

Here is what I did with 3 of them:

```
 [ComVisible(false)]
 public override string ToString()
 {
    return base.ToString();
 }

 [ComVisible(false)]
 public override bool Equals(object obj)
 {
   return base.Equals(obj);
 }

 [ComVisible(false)]
 public override int GetHashCode()
 {
   return base.GetHashCode();
 }
```

This doesn't work:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public override Type GetType()
{
  return base.GetType();
}
```

Here is the error message in Visual Studio when compile:

```
..GetType()': cannot override inherited member 'object.GetType()' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override
```

So, what should I do to hide the GetType() method from COM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should introduce a new COM interface and inherit your class from it with [`ClassInterfaceType.None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435295/need-of-classinterfacetype-none). This way you will only expose the methods in that interface.

Comment: Both of you were right, guys!

I implemented like you said - interface WITHOUT ToString() etc... 
Only methods that I needed.
In my class, I've set:
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Functions : IFunctions

and I implemented methods from IFunctions.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I thought COM used Interfaces and hides the implementation, so i would go with that. There is no way to hide GetType as fas as i know.